# How can I modify a variable inside a loop in java

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, lifetime

I have a function with the lifetime of an objet. This function starts when the objet is created and creates a new thread where it start decreasing this lifetime, and when it ends it erases the object from a list. The problem is that I want to increase this lifetime in some cases. But I can't modify the lifeTime variable because it must be final ("Variable 'lifeTime' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final"). ¿Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

```
for (time = lifeTime; time <= 0; time = time-1000 ){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    lifeTime = time;
}
```

Comment: You could just change the `time` variable within the loop and have `lifeTime` represent initial lifetime (`initLifetime`).

Comment: I've tried this way but it gives me the same problem :S "Variable ''lifeTime is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final"...

 for (beaconTimeLeft ; beaconTimeLeft <= 0; beaconTimeLeft-=1000; ){Thread.sleep(1000);}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the other context of your code so maybe there are better answers, but you can try and place your lifetime variable inside an array of size 1 (box it) and then you'll probably can modify its value

`final int[] lifetimeBox = ... //lifetime = lifetimeBox[0]`